# Configuring apache to use 81 port

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost, httpd.conf

some applications started to use my 80 port and it's became impossible to use xampp.

in host file I have

```
127.0.0.1   a1.com
```

So I changed httpd.conf to

```
Listen 81
ServerName 127.0.0.1:81
```

In httpd-vhosts.conf I also made changes

```
<VirtualHost a1.com:81>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/Work/XAMPP/htdocs/a1.com/web/"
    ServerName a1.com
    <Directory "D:/Work/XAMPP/htdocs/a1.com/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I saved everything , started Apache, Apache started successfully, tried to open page using a1.com , but received **404 - Not Found**.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Comment: You can't use IP as a server name in the `ServerName` directive. What is your apache version? What is error_log saying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a similar configuration. In the hosts file I have:

```
127.0.0.1     local.home.com
```

In httpd.conf I have:

```
Listen 81
```

And in httpd-vhosts.conf I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@home.com
    DocumentRoot "D:\PATH\TO\MY\FILES"
    ServerName local.home.com
    ErrorLog "logs/home-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/home-access.log" common
    <Directory "D:\PATH\TO\MY\FILES">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score -2):

you should add the port on the browser. http://localhost:81